# Angularjs : resource and $promise

Tags: angularjs

What is the good way to save in a for loop?

```
for (var i=0;i<$scope.annonces.length;i++){
   promises.push(Annonces.save($scope.annonces[i])).$promise;
}
$q.all(promises).then(function() { 
  blablabla
}
```

or

```
for (var i=0;i<$scope.annonces.length;i++){
   promises.push(Annonces.save($scope.annonces[i]).$promise);
}
$q.all(promises).then(function() { 
  blablabla
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried them? You haven't mentioned a specific problem

Comment: I have weird behaviour, datas of $scope.annonces[i] are not well save, the problem occurs randomly.

Comment: Is `$scope.announces` itself a `$resource` object? Does it have a `$promise` property? If so, the promises.push loop should be chained from that `$promise`.

Comment: $scope.annonces is an array of $resource , each $resource has a promise property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
promises.push(Annonces.save($scope.annonces[i]).$promise);
```

Comment: that's what I did first, so I hoped that the good solution would be the first proposal : )

Comment: @user1260928 first proposal will not work at all, because `$q.all` expects array of promises and you are passing resource.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for the map operator

```
var myPromises = $scope.annonces.map(function(annonce) { 
  return Annonces.save(annonce).$promise
});
```

This will generate an array of promises in a much more functional manner